# Create SQL Server Compact 3.5 from .net 4.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, .net-4.5, sql-server-ce-4, sql-server-ce-3.5

I have a C# application compiled on net 4.5.

I need to create a SQL Server CE 3.5 database file because it will be used on a Windows CE 6 device.

When I create a database from code using

```
SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
en.CreateDatabase();
```

it's version 4 and not compatible with net compact 3.5

How can I force the SQL Server CE version to 3.5 on net 4.5?

Comment: You may try to specify a Version in your connection string. Possibly you have to use "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=myPath\myData.sdf;" see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/

Comment: Do not use the OLEDB provider from .NET...

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference version 3.5.1.0 of System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll from your project instead of version 4.0.0.0.

You can install the 3.5 SP2 desktop runtime from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783

Comment: @ErickEJ I'm having the same problem, I've installed the 3.5 version and want to make sure if I make the changes in my app.config from <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" to System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5?

Comment: Also, I just did a Nuget search and found EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact.Legacy, so I'm assuming rather than changing the app.config is to remove 4.0 version and install this one correct?

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation is to switch to SQLite instead.  SQL Server Compact edition has been deprecated / discontinued.  Even MS has started recommending using SQLite for embedded development in latyer environments:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486593.aspx

SQLite databases are compatible between the desktop / server side and the mobile side.